# Row Security Level

Tags: sql-server, row-level-security

I am trying to create a row security level over my table for the user department

```
CREATE TABLE Student_Table 
(
    Title varchar(10) NULL,
    DateofBirth DATE NULL,
    BF1 varchar(10) NULL,
    Language varchar(20) NULL,
    Qualification varchar(20) NULL,
    Programme varchar(20) NULL,
    Curriculum varchar(20) NULL,
    Level int NULL,
    Department varchar(max) NULL
)
```

`Department` column contains

```
Level 1: General Staff
Level 2: IT Management
Level 3: Senior Managers
```

When I try create users

```
CREATE USER Manager WITHOUT LOGIN;
CREATE USER Level 1: General staff WITHOUT LOGIN;
CREATE USER Level 2:IT Management WITHOUT LOGIN;
CREATE USER Level 3: Senior Managers WITHOUT LOGIN;
GO
```

I get the following errors:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 35
> Incorrect syntax near '1'
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 36
> Incorrect syntax near '2'
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 37
> Incorrect syntax near '3'

Can someone please assist me.

Answer (score 0):

The error is simple. When name of an object should have space then whole name must be within `[]`.

```
CREATE USER Manager WITHOUT LOGIN;
CREATE USER [Level 1: General staff] WITHOUT LOGIN;
CREATE USER [Level 2:IT Management] WITHOUT LOGIN;
CREATE USER [Level 3: Senior Managers] WITHOUT LOGIN;
```

Answer (score 0):

The first part of troubleshooting is break your code into pieces and work out which line failed first..

It was

`CREATE USER Level 1: General staff WITHOUT LOGIN;` right?

All the prior stuff is irrelevant.

This is the correct syntax:

`CREATE USER [Level 1: General staff] WITHOUT LOGIN;`

This needs to be repeated for your other user creation.

But you should really avoid identifiers with spaces or special characters altogether